# Clickable modifier didn't work on Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

So i'm trying to initiate the navigation on the clickable modifier, but it doesn't work, so what i did is make a Toast function inside the clickable modifier, the toast message doesn't even show up when i click the item, so i figure out the clickable modifier didn't work, here's the part of my code.

```
@Composable
fun HomeContent(
    orderMovie: List<OrderMovie>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    navigateToDetail: (Long) -> Unit,
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    Box(modifier = modifier) {
        LazyColumn {
            items(orderMovie, key = { it.movie.id }) { order ->
                MovieListItem(
                    name = order.movie.name,
                    photoUrl = order.movie.photoUrl,
                    desc = order.movie.desc,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .clickable {
                            navigateToDetail(order.movie.id)
                            Toast.makeText(context, order.movie.id.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

any idea what i did wrong?

For more information : i've tried using the Log function inside the clickable modifier, but even the Log function doesnt return anything on the logcat

Comment: The reason `Toast` is not showing is because you didn't add `.show()` at the end. Secondly, I don't see `MovieListItem`, but are you sure that you gave the `modifier` you sent as a parameter as `modifier = modifier` in `MovieListItem` content.

Comment: If logging not work, look for the problem inside the `MovieListItem`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `Modifier` parameter is correctly provided to the `MovieListItem` root item (`Box` / `Row` / `Column` / etc.)

Try to only display something simple (the Toast or a log) in your clickable function to test the click.

Try to display a `Text` with a clickable function instead of the `MovieListItem` to be sure that the `.clickable` function is working.

PS : You missed the `.show()` after you `Toast.makeText()`.